# View pager with web views fast scrolling

Tags: android, webview, android-viewpager

I need to make view pager with webview on every page. App will download remote (large) images from server to device cache and when download completes it should appear in current webview. This is my view pager item layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:padding="1dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my instantiateItem method in view pager adapter:

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container,
                false);

        imgflag = (WebView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);

        imgflag.setBackgroundColor(0x000000);
        imgflag.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        imgflag.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
        imgflag.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        DownloadImageTask task = new DownloadImageTask(urls[position]);
        task.execute();


        ((ViewPager) container).addView(itemView);

        return itemView;
    }
```

And this is DownloadImageTask class:

```
private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    String imageUrl;
    String filename;
    public DownloadImageTask(String url)
    {
        super();
        this.imageUrl=url;          
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        Bitmap image = null;
        Log.d("Start", "Start downloading");
        filename=imageUrl.replace('/', '-');
        filename=filename.replace('.', '-');
        filename=filename.replace(':', '-');
        File file=new File(context.getCacheDir(), filename);            
        if(file.exists())
        {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(context.getCacheDir() + "/" + filename);
            return bitmap;
        }                          
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(imageUrl);
            HttpURLConnection ucon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            image = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(ucon.getInputStream());
            File cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();

            File imageFile = new File(cacheDir, filename);

            FileOutputStream fos;
            fos = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos);
            fos.close();
            fos.flush();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        return image;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        if(result!=null)
        {

            String style="width='100%'";
            if(result.getWidth()>result.getHeight())
                style="height='100%'";
            String base = context.getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath().toString();
            String imagePath = "file://"+ base + "/" + filename;
            String html = "<html><head></head><body><img " + style + " src=\""+ imagePath + "\"></body></html>";
            imgflag.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html","utf-8", "");
        }
   }
}
```

And everything works perfect when I scroll slowly, page by page... But if I scroll fast about 10-20 pages (without waiting for every to load), it doesnt work right. It will not crash or something like that, but view is just black. And started downloads won't stop when I leave page that started loading, it still loads images in background, so maybe it could cause problems? And when it doesnt load image, console says: nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.

Is there any simple fix for this problem? I should not use any external codes, libraries or something like that - i should code everything by myself.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the problem is that you are starting a large number of AsyncTasks in quick succession. These operate in their own thread. If you scroll through 20 pages, then you are simultaneously trying to download up to 20 images from a remote source. It is possible to cancel an AsyncTask by calling its `AsyncTask.cancel(true)` method, however this is not very helpful as you also have to check for `AsyncTask.isCancelled()` in your `doInBackground()` method. As you are only really conducting one long running task, this isn't very helpful. Furthermore your ViewPager is responsible for maintaining your WebView so determining when to call it would be difficult.

I would suggest attempting to download all the images as soon as the ViewPager adapater is instantiated. You would also need a placeholder image to display if the image is not yet downloaded.

So your AsyncTask would look something like this:

```
private class DownloadImages extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {  

    private List<String> mUrls

    public DownloadImagesTask(List<String> urls){  
        mUrls = urls;  
    }      

    protected Void doInBackground(){  

        for(String url : mUrls){  

            if(isCancelled())  
                break;  

            //Your code to download and save the files locally  
    }
```

And your ViewPager Adapter something like this

```
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {  

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager_item, container,
            false);

    imgflag = (WebView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);

    imgflag.setBackgroundColor(0x000000);
    imgflag.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    imgflag.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    imgflag.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);  

    String imageUrl = urls[position]  

    //Your code to turn url into filepath  
    //If file exists - display set WebView image = file 
    //Otherwise set WebView image to placeholder file 
}
```